# Another French pronunciation of 'visage'

Tags: choix-de-mot

I know that the French pronunciation of 'visage' is 'vee-ZAHZH', with the primary emphasis placed on the second syllable.

Can 'visage' also be pronounced (in French) as vih-SAHZH'? The 'ih' sounds like the 'i' in 'ignite'. The 'sahzh' sounds like the second syllable in the word 'massage'. Is this also a valid French pronunciation of 'visage'?

Many thanks.

Comment: *Visage* (one *s*) is pronounced /vizaʒə/ (and it means “face” or “visage” in English). *Vissage* (two *s*) is pronounced /visaʒə/ (and it means *screwing*… with a screwdriver or similar). There is only one /i/ sound in French whereas English has /iː/ and /ɪ/.

Comment: I'm closing this as a duplicate of the other question. You should really [look this up in a dictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/visage#French) first. If you are not satisfied with what's written in the dictionary, then edit your previous question, *quote* what the dictionary says and *explain why you are in doubt*. If you don't read IPA fluently have a look at [French IPA symbols here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA_for_French).